# Need alternative to Not IsEmpty() in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to check whether two textboxes have text in them.  If they both do, I want to replace box 1 with box 2. This is VBA   I'm using 
If Not IsEmpty(txtBox1) and Not isEmpty(txtBox2) then

but it's not going into the code.  I'd rather not use two negatives in an And statement.  What else is there?

The rest of the code is working.

Comment: `If txtbox1<>"" and txtbox2<>"" then` perhaps?

Comment: Since your condition requires both fields contain text then both cases are needed.

Comment: @findwindow "" is not the same as IsEmpty() in all cases.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon For text, it's same?

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
If Len(txtbox1)>0 And Len(txtbox2)>0 Then
    'Do something
End If
```

The `IsEmpty()` function is not for checking strings - it's for checking if a `Variant` has been set to a value or not; uninitialized variants are empty but a variant with a value is not. A valid string is not `Empty`.

Comment: This (`Len(txtbox1)>0`) is also faster than `txtbox1<>""` - Len() works with a string property rather than the string itself

Comment: @paulbica That is correct - VBA uses BSTR-s internally for strings, which are length-prefixed wide-character strings. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @paulbica How do you know what code works with what? Edit: nevermind, I guess it's something you just study XD

Comment: @findwindow What were you referring to with your comment?

Comment: How do you know something works with a property vs itself. What does property even mean? =P

Comment: @findwindow In paulbica's comment, he referred to the length-prefix of the internal implementation of `String` in VBA and VB6. This is something one would learn through reading the documentation for OLE automation (which is used throughout VBA / VB6). I learned these things through a lot of interfacing between C, C++ and VB6 in the past.

Comment: "...reading documentation for OLE automation..." yeaaaa.... so how many pages and how many documentations have you read =P Thanks! This is over my head (not reading any of this stuff) XD

Comment: @findwindow: as in the link in xxbbcc's comment, the string object contains a "length prefix": _A four-byte integer that contains the number of bytes in the following data string. It appears immediately before the first character of the data string..._ (VBA doesn't need to read and calculate the size of the string because this prefix provides direct access to the total number of characters)

Comment: Yea I followed the link hence realizing this is just something one studies because while what you said makes sense, I am still unsure what it fully means XD

Comment: didn't mean to duplicate the info but I was responding while other comments got written. Another interesting fact about the efficiency of `Len(txtbox1)>0` is that it uses less memory as well - doesn't access any string object, while `txtbox1<>""` access 2, the empty string ("") being created for no other reason than to calculate a size of 0)

Comment: See, to an amateur, len() seems more complex. It's a function vs something like <>"" But yea, makes sense the computer "thinks" differently. The bytes/memory thing is also overkill for me XD

Comment: I can see how at first it seems complex (I think it was for me as well), but once you get used to the notation, when you need to deal with millions of records, every optimization counts (exponentially) and you never go back to `<>""` out of habit

Comment: Thank you for the lesson ^_^ Will know to use len() going forward!

Comment: That's funny though. Instead of having the machine work for you, you're thinking like the machine/bending to its limitations. It's amazing how the thought process works ^_^;

Comment: This is exactly the information I needed. Thank you

Comment: @user1433308 I'm glad it helped. Please accept this answer if it was useful to you.